# How to stream from one PC to many easily?

Tags: video

I want to take programming lectures/workshops. In an ideal case, I will have a projector that can clearly show a complex UI and lots of text to people 50 meters away. But in real life, the limited range of projector, background light, poor eyesight of audience.

So I want a program to let my audience that allows them to connect to my computer over wifi and mirror my video in a window in their computers. I want the server and client to be as cross-platform as possible. It should be possible to limit bandwidth too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [bigbluebutton](https://bigbluebutton.org/) or [openmeetings](https://openmeetings.apache.org/), both are free, opensource, and as cross-platform as it possible.
If you want to just stream your desktop, you can use [obs-studio](https://obsproject.com/).